# Invoke activity call on refresh action in adpative card is returning "application/vnd.microsoft.error" error

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

We've implemented a Teams Bot with link unfurling functionality. When a link is pasted, a card displaying basic information is generated. We've incorporated a refresh feature in the card schema JSON to present a user-specific view after refreshing the card.

We are following this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/cards/universal-actions-for-adaptive-cards/sso-adaptive-cards-universal-action to enable sso logic for actions like refresh and other card actions.

Here while making login request, the invoke call is a successful one, but we are getting the below error for the response type :

{ 
"statusCode": 0, 
"value": { 
"code": "0", 
"message": "Unexpected response type for Status Code: 0 Expected responseTypes: application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive or application/vnd.microsoft.activity.message"
},
"type": "application/vnd.microsoft.error",

When I check for this error, I can see that this could be due to incorrect values passed for `tokenExchangeResource` in the request,

We are passing the below values for tokenExchangeResource :

`tokenExchangeResource: { id: uuid.v1(), uri: <Azure App Id>, providerId: null },`

Has anyone faced similar issue ?

Comment: Ensure that the response being sent from your bot is of the correct type. If you are sending an Adaptive Card, the content type should be 'application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive'. If you are sending a message, the content type should be 'application/vnd.microsoft.activity.message'. Check your bot's code to ensure that the correct content type is being set for the response.

Comment: @Sayali-MSFT
When we pass type as application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive and content is adaptive card, it works fine.
However we want to get authentication object from context and when authentication object/token is not there in the context we are trying to initiate sso by passing auth card in the createInvokeResponse.
There we get an error which says :
Unexpected response type for Status Code: 401 Expected responseTypes: application/vnd.microsoft.activity.loginRequest or application/vnd.microsoft.error.invalidAuthCode

Comment: Below is the code:
statusCode: 401,
            type: "application/vnd.microsoft.card.loginRequest",
            value: {
                text: "Please sign in",
                connectionName: "",
                tokenExchangeResource: {
                  id: uuid.v1(),
                  uri: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token",
                  providerId: null
                },
We are following this sample -https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/blob/main/samples/bot-sso-adaptivecard/nodejs/bots/botSSOAdaptiveCard.js